# Is it possible to see the removed content due to my flag in my own question?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, moderator-tools

Years ago I flagged a comment or maybe an answer for "Harassment, bigotry, or abuse" in my own question, and it was probably removed by a moderator. I just found out earlier today on my personal page that I have one helpful flag.

I am curious about the content I flagged. I cannot recall what it was. In my flag summary I can only see a link to the question, a reason and a date of the flag.

Is there a way to see the removed content in my question due to my flag? Or is it only visible by a privileged person? Or is it hidden/removed permanently?

Comment: Assume that any content here can disappear at any moment, and act accordingly (e.g., save an off-line copy, incl. cross-referenced content).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it was a comment, you can only ever see it again by becoming a moderator on the site.

If it was an answer or a question, it will be possible to follow the link and see the deleted content once you gain the [moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege and can see deleted posts.